# Clear the sort applied on a table from the code

Tags: sorting, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to clear the sort applied on a table from the code by using the `active` and `direction` fields but with no success:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

private clearSort() {
    // Reset the sort column
    this.sort.active = "";
    // Reset the sort direction
    this.sort.direction = "";
}
```

I looked into the [Sort Header Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api) but I didn't find any native method that helps to clear an applied sort on a given table.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the way to clear a sort is to re-apply the original sort order.

If the original sort order does not have a natural key, you may need to introduce an original order field in your data so you can sort by that field to "clear" any sorting that has occurred since the data loaded.

I haven't used `MatSort`, but in the absence of someone confirming otherwise, I would assume that to clear the sorting, you need to apply sorting as described above.

If the library supplied a reset, it would have to maintain the data in the original order in memory somewhere, which is why most libraries don't do this.

Comment: As you mentioned, in the absence of an already to use method to clear the sort (whether it is intended or not developed in the framework), the more logical option is to adopt a default sort upon which the clear method will be based

Answer (score 4):

You can set a default sort option and use sort function on the MatSort api to set that default option.

```
defaultSort: MatSortable = {
    id: 'defColumnName',
    start: 'asc',
    disableClear: true
};
```

then use sort function on MatSort directive:

```
this.sort.sort(this.defaultSort);
//default sort direction
this.sort.direction = 'asc';
```

Beware that the above code will trigger the sortChange event subscription.